# Google Apps Script - Query Parameters from opening form passed when submitting form

Tags: caching, google-apps-script, concurrency, google-forms, query-string

**Current Situation**

I have a Web App with an example URL that looks like this

```
https://script.google.com/a/domain.com/macros/s/Adlksjflf09_LEg8kdlf9/exec?ID=1
```

This Web App has a `doGet(e)` function that redirects it to a Google Form URL. Using the example above, it would look like this

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfi8jWUK2N4y03N4YYJ9p8Cyr2x06b1C6WgS_TcV98WM_ACtQ/viewform?ID=1
```

This ID field does not pre-fill any of the questions in the Google Form. Essentially, it's meant to hold information.

When a user submits a form response, I'm combining information from the query parameters as well as the form response and sending it as a payload to a webhook URL.

How I do that is by using `CacheService`. When a user opens the first URL, the `doGet(e)` function stores the e.queryString as a `Hash` in the cache. Then when a user submits the form, I can get the information from the cache and combine it with the formResponse.

The issue I have now is related to concurrency. There will be a case where more than 1 user has opened the first URL. This results in `Hash['queryString']` to be overwritten in the cache which is not what I want.

**Actual Question**

Is there a way to take query parameters from an onFormSubmit from a form and combine it with the form response without using `CacheService` since my current solution does not support concurrency?

From my understanding, the `onFormSubmit` trigger doesn't have an `e` (event variable) for me to do something like a e.queryString to get the query parameters. I may be wrong, need someone to confirm.

OR

Is it possible to cache information in such a way that I can keep track of whose query string is whose and then pull the appropriate information when submitting the form.

Comment: @Cooper but that's an Form Response event object. I'm thinking nothing in the Form Response contains the query parameters

Comment: @Cooper the full statement is "From my understanding, the onFormSubmit trigger doesn't have an e (event variable) `for me to do something like a e.queryString to get the query parameters.`" duly noted. it would be much more customisable with my own form. thanks

Comment: `There will be a case where more than 1 user has opened the first URL`(with ?id=1) Then the hash will be the same for both. `This results in Hash['queryString'] to be overwritten` with the same hash.